# Mysql 5.5 autocreate monthly partition

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have database table where there are around 10k rows inserted every day. The database is already has 10m+ records in it. I want to know how can I auto create partitions every month on this table so that I can fetch data in faster way.

Also are there any limitations on no of partitions created on a table.

Eg.

- 12 partitions for year 2000
- 12 partitions for year 2001 and so on...

the partitions should be auto created at start of each month.

My scheme has date column in it.

Comment: maybe time to look into bigdata datastores/databases?

Comment: but what if I want to do it with partitioning of table as I have other database too linked with it.

Comment: I would assume that a cron script that creates a new partition every month is what you need. I'm not an expert at partitioning at all but this page looks useful if google isn't your thing (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to run `ALTER TABLE` yourself periodically to add partitions. There's no feature of MySQL to automatically add partitions in response to data growth. But you could certainly create a cron job to do it. Or alternatively you could use a [MySQL EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html).

MySQL 5.5 allows a maximum of 1024 partitions per table, and MySQL 5.6 increases this to a maximum of 8192 partitions per table. So if you create 12 partitions per year, you could store at least 85 years' worth of data.

Note, however, that partitioning is not a magic solution to make all queries faster. The partitioning only helps when the optimizer can prune the partitions examined according to your query conditions. For example, if you partition by date, but then you run a query for all rows for a specific user regardless of date, the query must examine all partitions anyway, because rows for a given user may exist in any month.

At a growth rate of 10k rows per day, your table will increase by 3,650,000 per year. This is certainly pretty rapid growth, but not impossible to handle.

I work on some databases with hundreds of millions of rows, *without* using partitioning. Partitioning is one method of optimizing *certain* queries, but indexes are more flexible.

Comment: That was very informative thanks! I have have created indexes over 3 fields. `fund_code,scheme_code and date`. Still searching takes average of 15-20 seconds, I think it can go higher for larger fetch. Also to update you searches would only be on indexed fields. If I use cron jobs tell me would the entire table be rewritten every time? Also can I make future partitions all together, will that help me?

Comment: You can effectively split one partition into multiple partitions, which would be a typical way to extend a table using RANGE partitioning. You should just read though the [documentation on partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html).